# is $x^2$ a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^3+x^2-2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am unsure how to show if $x^2$ is a unit. Am I trying to show whether or not it's an invertible element in the quotient? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

In Let $u$ be the class of $x$ in $Q[x]/(x^3+x^2-2)$, we have $u^3+u^2-2=0$, thus $u^2(u+1)=2$, thus the inverse of $u^2$ is ${{u+1}\over 2}$.